# IOS NSNotificationCenter addObserver from subclass of NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have added an observer from `AppDelegate` and put this code inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptiong` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[internetReachability startNotifier];
```

Now I want to put this `addObserver` inside my custom class which is a subclass of `NSObject`?

EDIT:

this is my reachabilityChanged method:

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"change");
}
```

I put this method on the same class in which I call addObserver

Comment: reachabilityChanged method wasn't hit if I put it on that subclass of NSObject @Rage

Comment: Where is `reachabilityChanged:` selector defined? In the AppDelegate?

Comment: Also what parameters does it have? It would be better if you provide its definition.

Comment: You need to ensure couple of things - 1) You are calling `startNotifier ` method from your custom class and that the code is being executed. 2) Your custom object is alive as long as notification is expected to come. Typically a singleton object makes sense in your context.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the `reachabilityChanged` method, you need to post the notification you have registered in `AppDelegate` as below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```